# Ubuntu 16.04: No "Network" tab in Nautilus

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

This question is very similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932984/network-tab-disappeared-from-nautilus-ubuntu-16-04) (including its screen shot), but I have some additional information to share.

First, an automatic connection to a shared network drive (using [this method](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)) still works for me.  So the problem is not that the network is unavailable.

When I launch nautilus from the command line, I get the following output:

```
(nautilus:3555): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:3555): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:3555): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:3555): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:3555): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

The problem started after I followed [these instructions](https://opensourceinside.blogspot.com/2016/07/how-to-fix-failed-to-start-session.html?m=1) to fix a "Failed to Start Session" problem, which included reinstalling the Ubuntu desktop.  That worked to allow me to log in again, but then this error popped up.

Does anyone know why Nautilus is not longer showing the Network tab in its menu?  Or is there a next step I should do to debug?

Comment: Did you reinstalled Nautilus to see if works? Maybe any corrupted Nautilus extension. Try `sudo apt remove --purge nautilus | sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some of Nautilus extensions or itself became corrupted.

Usually the best option to do is to reinstall it. So:

`sudo apt remove --purge nautilus | sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus`

It will correct some misconfiguration about it.